# Does there exist any serialization library for c++ that is as easy as Google Gson/XStream for java?

Tags: c++, serialization

It seems like every library I've ever seen recommended doesn't offer an api as easy as this.

```
MyClass* instance = (MyClass*)SerializationUtility.serialize(someString);
```

Has anyone heard of something this easy for c++?
In hava there are a couple of libraries that are so easy to use for converting text into objects and objects into text. This is one of those "solved problems" things, which is why it surprises me that there is no buzz around a c++ library (that I have heard of.)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

<sub>8th result when you Google "c++ serialization". =/</sub>

Comment: That's not bad, actually, but I wanted something with an even simpler interface. Either way though, let stackoverflow be the destination for advanced or simple questions, the authoritative knowledge base of programming :/ <-without a bunch of these

Comment: @Guesto: Oh, I'm well-aware; I'm not discouraging it or anything. I'm just teaching you to fish. I doubt you'll find a simpler one; Boost's is rather simple.

Comment: @Guesto What aspects of Boost Serialization would you want to be simplified even further?